# How to dynamically hover over react-list elements when arrow keys are pressed?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) and I'm rendering the [Control](https://react-select.com/components#control) component as null, because I already have my own text input for the user search. With my custom input, the null Control component, and the rest of the react-select components, my drop down looks like this:

[image: img]

The issue is that I cannot use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between results.

I've decided to verify that this issue is because of the nullified `Control` component, however after rendering the default input field, the up and down arrows still do not work, as they do in their demos in the docs.

I've also tried setting `defaultValue={!!searchResults.length && searchResults[0]}`, but that does not work either.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up resolving this issue:

```
export const addEventListenerArrowUpAndDown = () => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    // Make sure the drop down is open. In my case, it's shown only
    // when the length of my searchResults array is not 0
    const searchResultsExist = !!store.getState().search.searchResults.length;

    if (searchResultsExist) {
      // Pull all elements with a common class name from the drop down (all elements
      // usually have only this common class, the rest is too dynamic and unreliable)
      const searchResults = Array.from(
        document.getElementsByClassName("MuiListItem-root")
      );

      // I initially tried using .indexOf, but that didn't work, so I'm using this way
      let currentlyPseudoHoveredElement = -1;

      // See if one of the items already are "hovered" over
      searchResults.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.style.background === "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)") {
          currentlyPseudoHoveredElement = index;
        }
      });

      // On Arrow Key down
      if (e.keyCode === 40 && !!searchResults.length) {
        if (
          currentlyPseudoHoveredElement !== -1 &&
          currentlyPseudoHoveredElement !== 4
        ) {
          // Set current background color to preferred color
          searchResults[currentlyPseudoHoveredElement].style.background =
            "#FFFFFF";
          // Set next element's background color to preferred color
          searchResults[currentlyPseudoHoveredElement + 1].style.background =
            "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)";
        } else {
          searchResults[0].style.background = "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)";
        }
      } 

      // On Arrow Key down
      else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        if (
          currentlyPseudoHoveredElement !== -1 &&
          currentlyPseudoHoveredElement !== 0
        ) {
          // Set current background color to white
          searchResults[currentlyPseudoHoveredElement].style.background =
            "#FFFFFF";
          // Set previous element's background color to preferred color
          searchResults[currentlyPseudoHoveredElement - 1].style.background =
            "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)";
        } else {
          searchResults[0].style.background = "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)";
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

export const addEventListenerOnEnterOpenPseudoHoveredElement = () => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      const searchResults = Array.from(
        document.getElementsByClassName("MuiListItem-root")
      );

      // In the event that the drop down is shown and one of the
      // elements is "hovered" over, open that URL that it points to
      // This also works if I use the actual mouse to hover over something; it will open the link this way
      searchResults.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.style.background === "rgba(85, 125, 146, 0.5)") {
          element.click();
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```